Issues while using a loop on a bash script
I am using mkvdts2ac3.sh script (see https://github.com/JakeWharton/mkvdts2ac3), and I have troubles to use it in a loop. This script is able to extract a dts track from a mkv file, convert it in AC3 and mux it back in the original mkv file. My problem is that I want to do it recursively for all dts tracks in the file.
I don't think this is a big issue but I can't find the solution, hope you will understand my problem guys!
So I am using a txt file where all the dts tracks ids are stored (ex: 1:fre \n 2:eng). It is working fine when I just let the echo line, it prints all the dts tracks correctly. But when I want to use the script, it stops each time after the first use.
Here is the part of the script in question :
        while IFS=: read -r track_id language; do
            echo "Extraction de la piste $track_id avec la langue $language"
            (bash "$mkvdts2ac3_path"/mkvdts2ac3.sh -f -t $track_id -v $merged_file) || continue
            sleep 5
        done < "tracks_info.txt"

I have no errors, just the main script is ending without doing the second dts track.

One possible cause is that (bash "$mkvdts2ac3_path"/mkvdts2ac3.sh -f -t $track_id -v $merged_file) consumed standard input, throwing away all the data from the second line onwards.

Indeed it was the problem, thank you Philippe ! I just modified the invocation of mkvdts2ac3.sh to explicitly redirect standard input from /dev/null to prevent it from consuming input meant for the loop and it works. I can continue now thanks again!
